# Excel 2013: How to put 1 for the lowest number, 2 for the second lowest number ....etc

Tags: excel

I have some values and I need to put to another column 1 for the lowest value, 2 for the second lowest value etc.

Comment: use [RANK](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rank-function-HP010335659.aspx) function

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your values are listed in A1-A5.  In B1 the equation would be =RANK(A1,$A$1:$A5,1).  This first part, A1, would change in each row.

Comment: You should respect what simoco already answer first in a comment... :)

Comment: wasnt there when I started typing.  Also I gave a more detailed answer :p

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly, but there is one little thing. I have two values that are equal, and it ranked them as "2" both, and the next one is 4. Is there any way that the next value would be ranked as 3 instead of 4?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot through rank function.  However if you are able to sort the list, then autofill values 1 to end.  Then re-sort back to the original order.